# get custom objects constructor function name

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

I made a little console application the other day and I'm wanting to print the data type before the value in the console.

I would like when an Object is created with the `new` keyword to retrieve the name of the Constructor function, but I'm having difficulty.

Is there any other way to retrieve the constructor name. I would not be able to modify the prototype with a custom constructor property reference.

```js
function Thing( name ){
  this._name = name;
}

Thing.prototype = {
  /*
  I cant do these
  constructor: Thing,
  toString: function(){
    return [object Thing];
  },
  */
  name: function( name ){
    return name != null
      ? (this._name = name)
      : name;
  }
}

var thing = new Thing('andrew');

// I have tried the following without success as it seems to be created by Object not Thing
console.log( thing.constructor );
console.log( thing.constructor.name );
console.log( thing.constructor.toString() );
console.log( Thing );
console.log( Thing.prototype );
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf( thing ) );
console.log( Object.prototype.toString.call(thing) );

// test whether thing is instanceof Thing
console.log( 'is it a thing?', thing instanceof Thing );
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Comment: without your prototype code, `thing.constructor.name` works just fine. this happens btw because `name` has to be inherited all the way from Function.prototype, so if you define a custom prototype, it shadows that low-importance inheritance for the name property.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. but why would that prevent `thing.constructor.name` from working

Comment: because this overrides the constructor-property wich is now inherited from Object. And points to the Object function/constructor

Comment: ok, so `thing.constructor=== function Thing`. `Thing.hasOwnProperty("name")===false` so, that function's `.name` comes from `Function.prototype`. But, `Thing.prototype` is in front of `Function.prototype`, so any conflicts it has will mask the inheritance. It is weird to see direct function.prototypes show up outside of an instance, but does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for explaining that @dandavis I understand where the issue lies now. if you answered it would be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Don't assign a Object to the prototype, 
assign each property to the existing prototype-object

```
function Thing( name ){
  this._name = name;
}

Thing.prototype.name = function( name ){
    return name != null
      ? (this._name = name)
      : name;
}

var thing = new Thing('andrew');

console.log( thing.constructor.name );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. this also makes sense to me. Generally I use `extend(thing.prototype, { ... stuff ... })` rather than `thing.prototype = {... stuff ...}` so I have never come across this, but thanks for pointing it out.